# DCOS/Mesos Kafka command to increase partition

Tags: apache-kafka, mesos, mesosphere, dcos

I have a Kafka cluster running on Mesos. I'm trying to increase number of partitions on a topic. That usually works with **bin/kafka-topics.sh --alter** command. Is this option exposed via dcos cli or kafka-mesos rest API? From what I see its not exposed.

If not, what is the best way to access kafka's cli within mesos installation?
Right now I use dcos cli to get broker IP and then in an adhoc way get to

```
/var/lib/mesos/slave/slaves/11aaafce-f12f-4aa8-9e5c-200b2a657225-S3/frameworks/11aaafce-f12f-4aa8-9e5c-200b2a657225-0001/executors/broker-1-7cf26bed-aa40-464b-b146-49b45b7800c7/runs/849ba6fb-b99e-4194-b90b-8c9b2bfabd7c/kafka_2.10-0.9.0.0/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh
```

Is there a more direct way?

Answer (score 0):

We've just released a new version of the Kafka framework with DC/OS 1.7. The new version supports changing the partition count via `dcos kafka [--name=frameworkname] topic partitions <topicname> <count>`.

See also: [Service documentation](https://docs.mesosphere.com/kafka-1-7/) ("Alter Topic Partition Count" reference)